# What is the tech stack for live streaming sites like Twitch? Especially the network protocols?

Tags: web-services, http, networking, network-protocols, live-streaming

What should I do if I want to embed a live streaming function in my website? There seems to be no solution via Google.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you intend to use some sort of browser plugin, embedding video on a website typically entails the [<video>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) tag. So, most likely, support for livestreaming would entail a networking method of your choosing when recording the live stream (UDP perhaps?) to your server, which would -- in turn -- transcode the data into a format that can be consumed via the <video> tag on the browser. If you only need to livestream between two browsers (like in video chat), then WebRTC is probably your solution.

With the <video> tag, [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) makes it possible for the client/server to highly customize the transport of the media streams. For example, a custom MediaSource could send the media using [web sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) if it so chose, for example (instead of as an HTTP stream). Because MediaSource extensions allow for such a wide degree of customization, it's really not possible to give one definitive answer regarding the protocols used to communicate with the browser.

And whereas the browser<->server protocols are easily discoverable (just open the developer tools when visiting one of these sites), the underlying server<->server protocols are not.